# Баг jquery ui при клике или ховере на пункт меню 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Вопрос по `jquery ui`.
 При фокусе клике или ховере на пункт меню появляется ошибка в консоли :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Скрипт работает, автокомплит показывается.

На одном сайте работает на другом не работает.

```
var json = {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Пункт 1",
          "link": "#link1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Пункт 2",
          "link": "#link2"
        },
        {
          "title": "Пункт 3",
          "link": "#link3"
        }
      ]
    };


$.widget( "app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    // Which class get's applied to matched text in the menu items.
    options: {
        highlightClass: "ui-state-highlight"
    },
    _renderItemData: function( ul, item ) {
            var str = "<a  href='"+ item.link +"' class='lv-link-search'>"+item.title +"</a>";
            // // Replace the matched text with a custom span. This
            // // span uses the class found in the "highlightClass" option.
            var re = new RegExp( "(" + this.term + ")", "gi" );
            var cls = this.options.highlightClass,
                template = "<span class='" + cls + "'>$1</span>",
                label = str.replace( re, template ),
                $li = $( "<li/>" ).appendTo( ul );
            // Create and return the custom menu item content.
            $( "<div/>" )
                .html( label )
                .appendTo( $li );
        return $li
    }
});




$(".js-lv-autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 5,
    highlightClass: "ui-state-highlight-term",
    //source:  source,
    source: function (request, response) {

            var result = (json.items.slice(0, 5));
            response(result);


    },
    appendTo: ".js-lv-submit-search",
    open: function() {
        var position = $(".js-lv-submit-search").position(),
            left = position.left, top = position.top;

        $(".js-lv-submit-search .ui-lv-autocomplete").css({
            left: 0,
            top: 65,
            width: '100%'
        });

    }

}).autocomplete( "widget" ).addClass( "ui-lv-autocomplete" );


<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-lv-autocomplete" style="display: block; width: 100%; top: 65px; left: 0px;">
      <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><a href="#link1" class="lv-link-search">Пункт 1</a></div></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><a href="#link2" class="lv-link-search">Пункт 2</a></div></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active"><a href="#link3" class="lv-link-search">Пункт 3</a></div></li>
    </ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zif001/2shadc6d/)

Comment: проверяйте HTML, скорее всего там нет нужного класса, по которому у вас вызывается скрипт

Comment: какая строчка в приведенном коде будет _all.js:28_?

Comment: в этой строке 
   label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || item.value;

Comment: @zif001, это просто гениально, задать вопрос, в котором написать ошибку и  выложить js-код, который не имеет к этой ошибке никакого отношения

Comment: Это кусок кода из jquery ui. Я думаю весь jquery ui нет смысла выкладывать. 
Jquery ui не может найти атрибут или значение из даты.
label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || item.value;

Comment: @zif001, я правильно понимаю, что вы считаете, что виновата библиотека jquery ui, а не ваш код?

Comment: Что значит виновата? Я написал о проблеме, может у кого-нибудь такая же проблема была., поэтому спрашиваю. Если не правильно вопрос поставил то извиняйте.